# psycopg2 - drawbacks of reusing cursors?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, python

I am new to Python and the psycopg2 module.

#### context

Working on a script that select data from MySQL, perform some operations (conversion of data-types and other "transformations"), and finally insert data into PostgreSQL using the `psycopg2` module.

#### main problem

I've read [on the official website of psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html#best-practices) that it is better to instantiate new cursors each time it is possible:

> When should I save and re-use a cursor as opposed to creating a new
>   one as needed?
>       Cursors are lightweight objects and creating lots of them should not pose any kind of problem. But note that cursors used to fetch
>   result sets will cache the data and use memory in proportion to the
>   result set size. Our suggestion is to almost always create a new
>   cursor and dispose old ones as soon as the data is not required
>   anymore (call close() on them.) The only exception are tight loops
>   where one usually use the same cursor for **a whole bunch** of INSERTs or
>   UPDATEs.

but the nature of my script seems to require the use of only one cursor for *a whole bunch* of inserts since I've add the check if the dataset is empty before try to insert in `psql`

```python
for query, dataset in dict.iteritems() : 
    if dataset:    # this is the check if value(dataset) is not empty
      try:
        cur_psql.execute( query + dataset )
      except psycopg2.Error as e:
        print "Cannot execute that query", e.pgerror
        cnx_psql.rollback()
        sys.exit( "Rollback! And leaving early this lucky script, find out what is wrong" )
    else:
      print "The dataset for " + query + " is empty, skipping..."
```

this code insert data in different psql tables at each iteration with

```
cur_psql.execute( key + value )
```

#### question

My doubt is if in my scenario, I will encounter any drawback using the same cursor for all the inserts. I was not able to understand if I am in the category where

> The only exception are tight loops
>   where one usually use the same cursor for **a whole bunch** of INSERTs or
>   UPDATEs.

Comment: If it is only `INSERT`s, you don't have to worry - you don't fetch the result set in any case.  So the answer is already in your post.  Please note that `psql` is only a client to PostgreSQL.

Comment: many thx dezso, for the naming clarification too I really appreciate, this will stick in my mind, you are always on the piece!